# Newsletter block at footer weird problem

Tags: newsletter

Magento 1.9.2.2, I'm trying to put a newsletter subscribe form at footer.

By using `{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}` the block is not showing up,

By using `{{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}` the block is showing, but not working.

Any ideas what the issue is and how to fix?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm.. that looks right to me and I tested it and it works fine as well when dropping it into a CMS page. You're certain that Newsletter/Block/Subscribe.php has not been modified or overridden?  Also as a sanity check, the Mage_Newsletter module is enabled, correct?

Comment: are you adding this in static block?

Answer (score 8):

Since the newest Security Patch / Release you need to add a permission for the block type under "System -> Permissions -> Blocks"

Comment: Lol, You are right, I forgot about that, It's working now. Thanks